Google play orders do not appear on the play console
I have a webview app. I redirect the user to payment screens in java using a javascript bridge. Many of the current orders appear on the console. However, some orders do not appear on the console (successful or unsuccessful) even though the user is premium. Has anyone experienced this question before?
I reviewed the logs. The user enters the payment screen, and if the payment is successful, he is directed to the page where his account will be premium.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
